# How to configure a custom list form header using SharePoint Rest API

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, sharepoint-rest-api, power-automate, flow

How to configure a custom list form header using SharePoint Rest API?

It can be done using GUI : [Configure custom header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-configuration#configure-custom-header) but I am interested in doing the same using Rest API calls from a flow.

Comment: Let me know if below solution works for you or if you face any issues while using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it using SharePoint REST API in Power automate flow using "Send HTTP Request to SharePoint" action.

Here are the details required for configuring the list form using JSON (with example data/values):

**Method**: POST

**Request URL**:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/JSONFormatting/_api/web/web/lists/getbytitle('DemoList')/contentTypes('0x010068C1DD7A88F89747A3F7FCACD851E20E')
```

Here you have to use the content type ID in the list for which you want to apply the JSON formatting.

**Body/Payload**:

```
{
    "__metadata": {
        "type": "SP.ContentType"
    },
    "ClientFormCustomFormatter": "{\"headerJSONFormatter\":{\"elmType\":\"div\",\"txtContent\":\"[$Title]\"},\"footerJSONFormatter\":{\"elmType\":\"div\",\"txtContent\":\"[$Description]\"},\"bodyJSONFormatter\":{\"sections\":[{\"displayname\":\"\",\"fields\":[\"Title\",\"Description\"]}]}}"
}
```

Here:

- `headerJSONFormatter` object is associated with the list form "header" layout.
- `[$Title]` and `[$Description]` inside the `headerJSONFormatter` and `footerJSONFormatter` object are internal names of column in this format: `[$InternalNameOfColumn]`. You can get the internal name of your SharePoint list columns by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)
- `Title` and `Description` in `bodyJSONFormatter` object are display name of columns

You can take above example as reference and convert this as per your requirements in the Power automate flow.

**Related thread**: [SharePoint Online - Removing faulty list form custom body JSON](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/6738)

Comment: Hi, thank you for pointing me to contentTypes.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Ganesh for your help, here is how it started to work for me:

1. GET `_api/web/lists/getByTitle('DemoList')/ContentTypes?$filter=Name eq 'Item'`

Extract the `StringId` from above API call response as the Content Type Id which will be used in the next step.

2. POST `_api/web/lists/getByTitle('DemoList')/contentTypes('StringIdFromPreviousStep')`

Set these additional headers:

```
IF-MATCH *

X-HTTP-Method MERGE

Content-Type application/json;odata=verbose
```

body example:

```
{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.ContentType"},"ClientFormCustomFormatter":"{\"headerJSONFormatter\":{\"elmType\":\"div\",\"txtContent\":\"test\"}}"}
```